# Azure DevOps pipeline version in Azure web services environment values

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, azure-webapps

Im looking to place Devops release version number of my code build  inside azure web services environment variables.

So that I can read environment variables from code and apply cache bursting based on version change.

Everytime there is a release I want to use the lattest build number and append to my assets to generate dynamic path.

So I need help in creating a connection between azure dev ops and azure web services..so environment variables holds latest version number.

Can you please guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that setting appsetting on App Service will restart the app, so make sure you use zero-downtime deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to get the build number inside your pipeline (and then use it inside your script or where you need it).

Also, you can customize run/build number as you wish: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Example:

```yaml
name: $(TeamProject)_$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r) # custom defined build name based on variables

steps:
  - script: echo '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # build number usage
```

To store variables in your environment, you can use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash